Help installing new outlet
I’m trying to install a new outlet for a wall mounted TV. My plan was to add an outlet downstream of the existing nearby outlet (below the TV). I checked the outlet and found it’s already passing through to a different downstream outlet somewhere, so all the receptacle screws are occupied. I have Wago 3-port connectors to work with, so would this be a correct solution?
Use the Wagos to connect a short pigtail to the existing wires (both upstream and downstream)
Connect the pigtail to the receptacle screws
Connect the new outlet to the receptacle’s other screws

in your area, are you legally allowed to do the work?

98 to 99% it is feeding another outlet/light.  About 1% it is powered by two breakers.  Make sure the tiny tabs between the screws are still on.

This sounds like an okay direction, except the three-port connector will leave you short by one port.  If you can tie in your new cable, the existing 2 cables, and a pigtail on each splice, it will look and feel more professional than leaving 5 wires attached to the receptacle.
This also assumes you have a box in the wall with integral cable clamps or tabs.  If not, it isn't a simple matter of opening a knockout.  The clamps are required for each cable.
As noted above, for a duplex receptacle it's a good idea to check both receptacles are on the same circuit.

The gang box has two unused ports (downward), so I think it will be OK to add another cable going into the box. Unfortunately the two existing cables are running up out of the box, and this one will need to go up as well, but I supposed I should be able to figure that out

Assuming the existing outlet that you say is "full" is a common residential outlet, I would rather simply replace it with a commercial grade type—the kind with clamps under each screw.  With those you can connect up to 4 cables to the outlet because each screw can hold two wires (though you still need to pigtail the grounds).  No need to stuff Wagos into a box.
